# Issues looping through an object to pull out property names when a keyword is found in an array

Tags: javascript, loops, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm a novice self taught programming working on a web app using angular, node.js, and the graph database noe4j.

I'm trying to pull out the names of terms that contain the label "Core" in their label array using the underscore library method _.contains. I'm stuck on figuring out the right syntax and any pointers would be greatly appreciated (including ways to avoid having to ask annoying syntax questions on SO).

I'm thinking I either have an issue with how I think the loop is going through the object (would each 'item' consist of what is enclosed in a set of {}?) or the way I'm trying to identify the keys within the loop is totally off.

Sample of returned data sample:

```
[{"name":"Sciences","labels":["Term","Science"]},{"name":"Image","labels":["Type","Image","Core"]},{"name":"GIF","labels":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Infographic","labels":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Chart","labels":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Photo","labels":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Microscope","labels":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Telescope","labels":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Text","labels":["Type","Text","Core"]}]
```

Angular Controller:

```
    function typeCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url:'/query/type' }).
        success(function(data){
            var theList = [];
            for(var item in data) {
                if (window._.contains(item.labels, "Core") === true) {
                    theList.push(item.name);
                }
            }

            $scope.display=theList;
            $scope.test = theList;
        }).
        error(function(data){
            $scope.type="Error :("
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is an array not an object so `for(var item in data)` gives you indices like 0,1,2 and this may be an issue

So you should use

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
```

And to find whether labels array contains **Core** , you can use basic indexOf method

```
function typeCtrl($scope, $http){
    $http({method:'GET', url:'/query/type'}).
        success(function(data){
            var theList = [];
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                if (data[i].labels.indexOf("Core") > -1){
                    theList.push(item.name);
                }
            }

            $scope.display=theList;
            $scope.test = theList;
        }).
        error(function(data){
            $scope.type="Error :("
        });
};
```

See sample fiddle to know the difference : http://jsfiddle.net/jmBjD/

Comment: Prasath, thank you so much for your help. This cleared a lot up for me. In my head I was dealing with an object- I need to learn to read the code I'm looking at...